# Easiest way to draw a image on JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I am a  beginner in java . I have a image called `1.png` . I was trying to display it on my `JFrame` , but when I run the code , the frame runs but there is no image . Here is my code :

```
package practice;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Practice
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Jf ob = new Jf();
        ob.setVisible(true);
    }
}
public class Jf extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

BufferedImage img = null;
public Jf() 
{
    initComponents();
    try 
    {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("1.png"));
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {

    }
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, rootPane);
}


   //below the code is auto-generated by netbeans , i did nothing




/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Jf().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Restriction :

> I can't use `JLabel` here

So ,please mention my error and try to write correction so that I can understand easily.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have two main methods - which are you calling?

Comment: 1) Change `catch (IOException e) 
    {

    }` to `catch (IOException e) 
    {
e.printStackTrace();
    }` 2) *"I can't use `JLabel` here"* Why not? 3) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: 4) `Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, rootPane);` that code draws the image back onto itself, achieving nothing. 5) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Make sure you log any errors instead of ignoring them

Answer (score 1):

Use a JPanel. Include this in your JFrame class:

```
public static class CustomPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    CustomPanel(width, height) {
        super(width, height);
    }
    void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    } 
}
```

And in your main method, include this:

```
ob.add(new CustomPanel(ob.getWidth(), ob.getHeight()));
```

Comment: Also, throw that code in a compiler, cause I doubt it'll work

Answer (score 1):

First, look the path of your image. You need to put your image in the project root. (Or you can use absolute path like "C:/.../yourfile").

Do not let the exception empty. Write e.printStackTrace() because here you cannot see if your exception is thrown.

You need to put your code into paintComponent of your pane.